# Accessing navigator.plugins in Firefox using Add-on SDK

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, navigator

How to access navigator.plugins object in main.js file? I use a Firefox Add-on SDK.
    ​

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var windows = require("sdk/window/utils");
var window = windows.getMostRecentBrowserWindow();
console.log(window.navigator.plugins);
```

Answer (score 3):

Every add-on comes with it's own "hidden" window, that could be used for some stuff. It's not well documented, but you should be able to do something like:

```
let { window: {navigator} } = require('sdk/addon/window');
console.log(navigator.plugins);
```